# Slim 4 Error 404 not found on nginx web server

Tags: nginx, slim

Please help me, I want to move the project rest api (Slim 4 use Design Pattern) from apache to nginx, but I haven't found a solution to this problem, how to convert .htaccess to nginx server configuration, the error I found is always 404 (Slim / Middleware / RoutingMiddleware.php)

thank you for your help

[image: root project]

[image: error 404]

this server config nginx

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;

index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
autoindex off;
server_name _;

location / {
           
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;

}   

location ~ \.php$ {

             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
             include fastcgi_params;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
             fastcgi_index index.php;

}

    location /FjbBaseApi {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /FjbBaseApi/public/index.php;
    rewrite ^/$ /public/ break;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1 break;
    
  }
   

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}

Comment: The public/ directory must be the root. Have you tried `root /var/www/html/public;` ?
Also try to set the Slim base path to `$app->setBasePath('/FjbBaseApi');`

Comment: thank you for helping, I tried it and it worked.